# Transparent app icon for iOS 4?

Tags: iphone, icons, ios4

If I use a png file with transparent background as the app icon in iOS4, the compiler will change its background to black. How can I preserve its transparency?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Transparent application icons are not allowed. The [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW2) makes it clear that alpha transparency is not allowed and elaborates:

> **Give your application icon a discernible background.** Icons with visible backgrounds look best on the Home screen primarily because of the rounded corners iOS adds. This is because uniformly rounded corners ensure that all the icons on a user's Home screen have a consistent appearance that invites tapping. If you create an icon with a background that disappears when it's viewed on the Home screen, users don't see the rounded corners. Such icons often don't look tappable and tend to interfere with the orderly symmetry of the Home screen that users appreciate.
>
> **Be sure your image completely fills the required area.** If your image boundaries are smaller than the recommended sizes, or you use transparency to create “see-through” areas within them, your icon can appear to float on a black background with rounded corners.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is impossible.

Comment: Agree. It's impossible and not been allowed by Apple. This is by design. They don't want any other outline of app icon except rounded box.

Answer (score 0):

Did you specify

```
UIPrerenderedIcon  YES
```

in your plist file? The standard effects would make the transparency useless...

I think transparent icons are discouraged, and I think you might have a hard time making it through the review (that is, if it is technically possible at all).

Comment: Xcode 3.2.3 I get my transparent part colored black regardless of UIPrerenderedIcon is True or False.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but background will be filled by black color. And your app may be rejected by censors of App Store.